# Npx fails on Azure App Service deployment

Tags: node.js, azure, npx

I'm trying to deploy a Node.js (Remix) application to an Azure App Service instance. After installing the npm packages, the post-install script must run for the Remix app to eventually work. The post-install script is `npx remix setup node`.

Unfortunately, the deployment fails because of the following reason:

```
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run
```

I get the same error when trying to use other npx commands, as `npx prisma generate`. I tried `npm exec` as well instead of `npx`.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

- In startup command try using  `npx serve -s build/`
- Also, under your app service Settings blade check all the general settings.
- Make sure that your web.config was published along with your app.